Issues in jupyter notebook in SageMath 10.3 installed in Anaconda
Currently, I am using ubuntu 22.04. I have installed SageMath 10.3 inside Anaconda using the following command:
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority strict
conda create -n sage sage python=3.9

When I open jupyter notebook using conda activate sage and sage - n jupyter, it opens a notebook (in web-browser) which has very less functionalities (pic 1), i.e., most the keyboard shortcut does not work and some other properties are missing, which are generally present in jupyter notebook (pic 2) installed in any other python environment.
I am not sure which packages needs to upgraded as I checked all pip packages are already upgraded in the sage environment.
Can anyone help me out in this issue ?
Jupyter-Notebook-Needed
Jupyter-Notebook-Installed
